Install Visual Studio 2015
My employer needs me to work on Windows Embedded Compact 2013 targeting .NET Compact Framework 3.5 or 3.9 using Visual Studio 2015. My computer is using Windows 10 x64.
The employer has an active MSDN license and downloaded mu_visual_studio_2015_update_3_x86_x64_dvd_8923065.iso for me. But when installation is attempted, I get the following error about "Update 3 - Setup blocked".

VS 2003.NET and VS2022 are already installed on the computer, though none of the VS2015 family have ever been installed.
After some research, I stumbled on this Microsoft article about how to resolve

Error - This update requires Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 to be installed

Looks promising, but none of the mitigating steps in that article have helped. In particular, the mitigation asked you to install vs2015.3.exe (already on the DVD) which gives exactly the same error.

How to get around this problem?
Is there a way to dig into exactly what error or pre-condition is blocking the installation?


What you have here is just the update package. You have already stated that VS 2015 has never been installed and you cannot install an update for a product that is not installed. You will need to download the VS 2015 installer first. You should be able to find links to older versions from the VS downloads page. Details can be found on the linked duplicate

@phuzi: I already visited that page and the "Visual Studio" editions (apart from "with update 3") are marked as "Not available".

If your employer has an active MSDN licence then they should be able to grab that download for you. They'll show as not available if you're not signed in with an account that has them available.
